# How do I disable items after the selected item in an HTML select using JavaScript or JQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a select with 5 items, if user will select the third q nearby items have become disabled......

The items below the selected item should not be selectable.

**[DEMO]**[1](http://jsfiddle.net/welguri/Dm454/)

Example:

```
<select class="form-control" name="itens" id="itens">
    <option value="1">- 1 -</option>
    <option value="2">- 2 -</option>
    <option value="3">- 3 -</option>
    <option value="4">- 4 -</option>
    <option value="5">- 5 -</option>
</select>
<div id="result"></div>
```

JQuery Code Sample:

```
$('#itens').change(function(){
 $(':selected').each(function(value, i){
    if($('option:selected')){
        var valor = $(this).attr('value');
        $('#result').html(valor);
    }
    //$(this).attr('disabled',true)
 });
});
```

I do not have much knowledge in jquery. 
I need to develop a page to make requests.

*??*
When choosing an item select it poderar not choose those below as a fee will be applied, and can only escolhar items up as they are other fees. 
*??*

Those items below the selected item must become disabled.

Comment: Please attach the code you have tried so far and describe the problem with your code

Comment: I would suggest using a question mark somewhere when asking a question.

Comment: This is really a job for checkboxes, not a SELECT.

Comment: Mounted system with select.

Comment: @Huangism based on the example of @ RGS, it would http://jsfiddle.net/welguri/Dm454/4/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$(document).on('change', '.form-control', function () {
  $(".form-control option:selected").prop('disabled','disabled')
        .siblings().removeAttr('disabled');   
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/m78mR/1/

**Update:**

```
$(document).on('change', '.form-control', function () {
          $(".form-control option:selected").next().prop('disabled','disabled');   
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/HXbq6/

Comment: thanks for the help, but when I used your code, you only need the desabilitase q are below the option selected and not when the site loads.

Comment: @Welguri, I couldn't understand what you told. You want all the options enabled during page load?

Comment: @RGS.The system thus he proceeds, the User chooses between 102 payment forms, each has different rate. 
Assuming that the User has chosen the seventh option, the parti of the option he chose were disabled by the end, he can only choose between the first and seventh.

Comment: @Welguri, I have added one more demo in my answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks .... It's almost this boss, because if I have 102 items to choose from .... when you choose the option below that the other must be disabled until the end.